# Multi-website setup. website code in all generated urls

Tags: url-rewrite

I've got several websites running on magento 1.8.1 and I recently noticed something has changed. I have no idea how this change happened, or how long it has been like this. I do know that it was behaving correctly at some point and now it's different.

In the configuration and store management, I set up the following websites with the following website codes:

```
Website 1:
Name: Site A
Code: site_a
Base URL: httq://site-a,com/

Website 2:
Name: Site B
Code: site_b
Base URL: httq://site-b,com/

Website 3:
Name: Site C
Code: site_c
Base URL: httq://site-c,com/
```

Now when I visit the sites, the urls that magento is generating look like this:

```
httq://site-a,com/site_a/product-1.html
httq://site-a,com/site_a/product-2.html

httq://site-b,com/site_b/product-1.html
httq://site-b,com/site_b/product-2.html

httq://site-c,com/site_c/product-1.html
httq://site-c,com/site_c/product-2.html
```

They should look like this:

```
httq://site-a,com/product-1.html
httq://site-a,com/product-2.html

httq://site-b,com/product-1.html
httq://site-b,com/product-2.html

httq://site-c,com/product-1.html
httq://site-c,com/product-2.html
```

Anyone know what might have caused this? Or what I can do to fix it? Maybe just point me in the right direction to start looking and change the code that generates the urls?

ps. sorry the urls look funky, the site wouldn't allow me to post a comment with lots of links. just replace the qs with ps and the commas with periods. you get the idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this setting out from Magento admin:

```
System Configuration -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls
```

This setting should be set to no.

Comment: OH haha so obvious. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!